# Cannot call ubuntu 'ulimit' from python subprocess without using shell option

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

When I try to call ulimit -n from subprocess, i.e.

`subprocess.check_output(['ulimit', '-n'])`

I get the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

This is strange, because the command is valid on the command line. Previous answers to similar questions focus on the need to input the command in the format of a list, which I have done. Other answers have mentioned that alias commands can cause problems for subprocess, but ulimit is not a alias. If I use the `shell=True` option the code works. But I would like to understand why.

Comment: @rdas it's a built-in, there exist no such binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ulimit` is a wrapper around a system call to limit the resources of the current process. Because it acts on the current process, it needs to be called on the current process or it has no effect.

For this reason, the shell implements it as a built-in, so there is no such binary.

If you were to create a shell to just call `ulimit`, and then kill the shell, you have accomplished nothing, because the process which has the limits is then killed. This is why things like `cd` that affect the current process need to be implemented like that in the shell.

This means that you cannot call it as a subprocess in python. Fortunately, python has a module to wrap it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html